# Overlay view being shown, but not removed

Tags: ios, swift, residemenu

I have a BaseViewController and a [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) that uses my MenuViewController. There are many possible "Home" screens that all inherit from this same BaseViewController. MenuViewController also inherits from BaseViewController.

I would like an overlay to be shown on the home screen and then disappear when the Menu is no longer in focus. **So far, I can only get the overlay to show, but not disappear.**

The overlay disappears if I tap one of the menu items, which performs a segue to the appropriate subclass of BaseViewController (for example, the Home screen or Settings screen). This effectively refreshes the screen, and I think I could keep a reference to the caller and segue back to it if I can't find a better solution.

Things I have tried:

- `overlay.removeFromSuperview()`
- `view.sendSubview(toBack: overlay)`
- `overlay.isHidden = true`
- `overlay.alpha = 0.0`
- Moving `hideOverlay()` into MenuViewController.
- Using `super.overlay` within MenuViewController instead of simply `overlay` or `self.overlay`.

I can confirm that all lines of code are hit with breakpoints, but the overlay view does not go away. BaseViewController's viewWillAppear() is not called when I tap to make the menu go away, because its subclass is already in view (just pushed to the side a bit).

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

**BASE VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
import UIKit
import SideMenu

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    let overlay = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup
        overlay.frame = self.view.frame
        overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        overlay.alpha = 0.5
        overlay.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        overlay.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(overlay)
    }

    // WORKS
    func showMenu() {
        // menuLeftNavigationController is MenuViewController.
        self.present(SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController!, animated: true) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.overlay.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.overlayColor // Already defined.
    }

   // PROBLEM IS HERE
   func hideOverlay() {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.overlay.setNeedsLayout()
            self.overlay.layoutIfNeeded()

            self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      }
   }

}
```

**MENU VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
import UIKit
import SideMenu

class MenuViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Tableview boilerplate
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // BREAKPOINTS CONFIRM THIS CODE EXECUTES.
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.hideOverlay()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `viewWillDisappear` when you call `self.hideOverlay`, you're calling that on your `MenuViewController`.

When `showMenu()` is called, you present the `MenuViewController` and then set the overlay background colour on the *presenting* view controller.

I guess, what you want to do here is in the completion of the `MenuViewController`, dismiss method do:

```
if let presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController as? BaseViewController {
    presentingViewController.hideOverlay()
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, it seems like this check fails, as presentingViewController is UIViewController, not BaseViewController. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: In the code above the class where `self.present` is being called is named `BaseViewController`, the property `self.presentingViewController` will be typed as a `UIViewController`, but using the option cast `as?` should be successful.

Comment: You could try setting your `MenuViewController`'s `modalPresentationStyle` to `overCurrentContext`, as when you call `present` from your base class, it may be delegating the presentation to another view further up the heirarchy